# How access to localhost:4200 running on ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, prefect

On my EC2 I have loaded a python script running a prefect flow and I want to access to the UI from a web browser. This UI is running on localhost:4200.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ prefect orion start 

 ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ _____    ___  ___ ___ ___  _  _
| _ \ _ \ __| __| __/ __|_   _|  / _ \| _ \_ _/ _ \| \| |
|  _/   / _|| _|| _| (__  | |   | (_) |   /| | (_) | .` |
|_| |_|_\___|_| |___\___| |_|    \___/|_|_\___\___/|_|\_|

Configure Prefect to communicate with the server with:

    prefect config set PREFECT_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4200/api

View the API reference documentation at http://127.0.0.1:4200/docs

Check out the dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:4200
```

To this end I have create an inbound security:
[image]

I have tried to access it with chrome with the url : `https://ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4200` (`<EC2-IP:Port>`)

But I have the following error in the chrome tab :

"**This website can't be reached**
ec2-x-xxx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com doesn't authorize the connection."

In another terminal connect to my instance i can curl the localhost:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ curl http://127.0.0.1:4200
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" id="favicon-32" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/ico/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" id="favicon-16" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/ico/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/ico/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/ico/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Prefect Orion</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.c3b9a55d.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.dbace0e3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
With the suggestion of @Jayce, I bind the prefect IP to 0.0.0.0 in order to access It from the web `export PREFECT_ORION_API_HOST=0.0.0.0`

I can now connect to the UI running on my instance:

[image]

But in this configuration prefect don't retrieve the flow I have started on the EC2. I need to also change the prefect api path:
`export PREFECT_API_URL="http://x.xxx.xxx.xx:4200/api"`

Comment: Can you `curl` the website from within the server?

Comment: Yes I can, I edit my question to display the result i get

Comment: Does the VPC have a route to an internet gateway?

Comment: I don't know. How can I check it ?

Comment: Select the route table associated with your vpc. does it have a route to an `igw-*`?

Comment: VPC on my org indeed have target route in this format, but as I don't create a VPC when creating my project how can which is associated with my instance ? Should <i create one ?

Comment: Have you actually tried accessing it on http and not https? What do you get when you do `curl -v http://ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4200` (http and not https)

Comment: @Riz Yes I have tried with both http and https. When do your command I get the same return as the one I have done in my instance (since I have bind the prefect ip).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must bind to 0.0.0.0 ip not 127.0.0.1 like default if you want access it from network.

I never used prefect, but from it's document, you can try this command to change bind ip:

```
export PREFECT_ORION_API_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: It almost works, the UI is display but not "connected" to the flow on my EC2. I display the error on my question.

Comment: Ok, we should have some small changes. Instead of bind to 0.0.0.0 ip, you can bind to  your public ip of ec2

Comment: Or another way betters, you can try set this setting to PREFECT_API_URL =http://<your-ec2-ip>:4200/api 
https://docs.prefect.io/concepts/settings/#prefect_api_url

Comment: I export this new api path but I have this error : ERROR:    `[Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('x.xxx.xxx.xx', 4200): cannot assign requested address`

Comment: It's working now. I don't know why it wasn't before :/

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 running on Oracle Cloud instance (amd64)

Answer (score 1):

For folks using Prefect >= 2.8.1, following worked for me. Execute these bash commands in your EC2 instance (linux based).

```
prefect config set PREFECT_API_URL=http://<ec2-public-ip>:4200
prefect config set PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST=<ec2-public-ip>
prefect server start
```

This will create `profiles.toml` file in the `.prefect` directory, or update it if already exists. The dashboard and the flows should be accessible now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the public IP address

```
http://<public_ip>:4200/
```

Comment: I got the same error in my web browser: "this website can't be reached"

Comment: Are you using any proxy, like nginx or apache?

Comment: I didn't configure one, but I'm using an aws sandbox within my org maybe there is one. How can I check it ?

Comment: check the `/etc/` directory and see if there is any directory with name nginx or apache. You can also run these commands `sudo service nginx status` and `sudo service apache2 status`

Comment: I don't have this directory. ``` [ec2-user@ip-xx ~]$ ls
sqlite3  test_folder  test.py``` and both of these commands return "Unit apache2.service could not be found"